# Grails 2.4.4, Hibernate3, mysql: Queries based on date getting wrong results

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, mysql-connector

I am getting wrong results with a query based on a date field, I have the following domain class

```
class Foo {
   String fooName
   Date fooDate
   static constraints = {
   }
}
```

Then I have the following method

```
def index() {
    Date d1 = new Date()
    Date d2 = new Date()

    //day 1 of current month 00:00:00
    d1.date = 1;
    d1.hours = 0;
    d1.minutes = 0;
    d1.seconds=0;

    //day 5 of current month 00:00:00
    d2.date = 5;
    d2.hours = 0;
    d2.minutes = 0;
    d2.seconds = 0;

    for(day in d1..d2){
        Foo f = new Foo(fooName:"fooName", fooDate:day);
        f.save(flush:true)
    }
    println "${d1} ${d2}"
    println "search Foo for each day..."
    def fooList
    for(day in d1..d2){
        println "${day}"
        fooList = Foo.findAllByFooDate(day)
        fooList.each{
            println "${it}"
        }
    }

    Date dayAfter
    for(day in d1..d2){
        dayAfter = new Date(day.time)
        dayAfter.date++
        println "foo between ${day} and ${dayAfter}"

        fooList = Foo.executeQuery("FROM Foo where fooDate>=:start and fooDate < :end", [start:day, end:dayAfter])
        fooList.each{
            println "${it} ${it.fooDate}"
        }
    }        
}
```

In console I'm getting the following output

```
 search Foo for each day...
 Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 CST 2014
 Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 CST 2014
 Wed Dec 03 00:00:00 CST 2014
 Fri Dec 05 00:00:00 CST 2014

 foo between Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 CST 2014
 hibernate3test.Foo : 2 Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 CST 2014
 foo between Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Wed Dec 03 00:00:00 CST 2014
 hibernate3test.Foo : 3 Wed Dec 03 00:00:00 CST 2014
 foo between Wed Dec 03 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Thu Dec 04 00:00:00 CST 2014
 hibernate3test.Foo : 4 Thu Dec 04 00:00:00 CST 2014
 foo between Thu Dec 04 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Fri Dec 05 00:00:00 CST 2014
 hibernate3test.Foo : 5 Fri Dec 05 00:00:00 CST 2014
 foo between Fri Dec 05 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Sat Dec 06 00:00:00 CST 2014
```

Note that the dynamic finder findAllByFooDate() is not getting results.

I would expect that the "foo" object between Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 CST 2014 would be hibernate3test.Foo : 1 (with fooDate:  Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 CST 2014) not hibernate3test.Foo : 2.

I'm using mysql-connector-java:5.1.29 and hibernate:3.6.10.18

When I switch to mysql-connector-java:5.1.22 (older version) I get the following output

```
search Foo for each day...
Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 1
Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 2
Wed Dec 03 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 3
Thu Dec 04 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 4
Fri Dec 05 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 5

foo between Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 1 2014-12-01 00:00:00.0
foo between Tue Dec 02 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Wed Dec 03 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 2 2014-12-02 00:00:00.0
foo between Wed Dec 03 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Thu Dec 04 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 3 2014-12-03 00:00:00.0
foo between Thu Dec 04 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Fri Dec 05 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 4 2014-12-04 00:00:00.0
foo between Fri Dec 05 00:00:00 CST 2014 and Sat Dec 06 00:00:00 CST 2014
hibernate3test.Foo : 5 2014-12-05 00:00:00.0
```

This is the correct output, the dynamic finder is getting results and the objects between the dates are the ones I was expecting, any idea on why with any version of mysql connector > 5.1.22 the  queries won't work correctly? Is this a bug? or I'm missing something?

Edit: Using a native SQL query gets the right results, maybe this is a hibernate issue?

Comment: I'd try to flush a session.

Comment: Even after the .save(flush:true) call?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, my bad.